# How do I find the previous line without writing an inefficient subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have this query (and have encountered or coded a bunch of similar ones during my life :) ) which is extremely inefficient in terms of performance, due to the subquery.

I'm running pgsql currently but have had this issue with mysql and mssql as well.

Sometimes I can use MAX() but here I have 2 different columns: runners.id (the one I need to find my data) and runners.updated_at (the one on which I could do MAX()).

Any tips?

```
SELECT
ROUND(CAST(AVG(DATE_PART('day', current_claim_event.updated_at - claims.created_at)) AS NUMERIC),1)
AS average, count(*)
FROM claims_events current_claim_event
INNER JOIN claims ON claims.id = current_claim_event.claim_id
WHERE current_claim_event.id = (
SELECT runners.id
FROM claims_events runners
WHERE runners.claim_id = current_claim_event.claim_id
ORDER BY runners.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Use `lag()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: lag()? I must be missing something but I don't see it in the doc and have never heard of it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Comment: ok I see - let me try to understand it, it does look like it is what I want